# expand macros in makefile

Tags: macros, makefile

Some makefiles are too large, define lots of macros. It's hard to understand. Is there any tool that can expand macros in makefile and output the new makefile? (Just as the -E option of gcc, which expands the macros in c source file)

Comment: If a make file is too large, won't expanding the macros result in another make file which is too too large ?

Comment: make -n some-target ? It may not be as full-featured as you are looking for, but I use the -n flag all of the time to see what the macroexpansion is going to do, before I commit to running the make target.